# Why does Consistency not imply Soundness?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

A theory $T$ is consistent iff there's no sentence $\varphi$ s.t. $T \vdash \varphi$ and $T \vdash \neg\varphi$.

A theory $T$ is sound iff all its axioms are true.

I can see why soundness implies consistency, since if all the axioms of a theory are true, and suppose the theory has a truth-preserving proof system, then every statement that can be derived from our theory must be true. There's no way we could derive a contradiction or a false sentence.

I'm not quite sure why consistency doesn't imply soundness. Do I have to show that there could be a consistent theory $T$ which has a false axiom?

Comment: [Soundness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness) means that the rules of the systems prove only logical consequence of the axioms. If an axiom is not a logical contradiction (a formula that is always false) for sure there is a model where it is true.

Comment: See also the post [Consistency vs Soundness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3060828/hilbert-program-consistency-vs-soundness)

Comment: Consider e.g. the axiom $\exists !x (x=x)$. For sure it is false in $\mathbb N$ but it is true in every "universe" with a single element.